Bindings not updated by DataContext updates
We are using MVVM for our WPF application, I have created an extension for ContentControl for a dialog footer, this footer contains buttons. We set the button commands from the ViewModel in the xmal file.
The issue is that the button commands are not updated when the DataContext is updates - the only way I have found to make it work it to change the binding to TwoWay, but then this means I have to make all the commands non-ReadOnly.
It is clearly some binding issue, but I cannot spot any other solution to change to TwoWay bindings, maybe someone else can pinpoint what I am doing wrong here:
ViewModel:
public class EditorViewModel : ObservableObject, INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    public EditorViewModel()
    {
        CancelCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(OnCancelAsync);
        CloseCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(OnCloseAsync);
        ConfirmCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(OnCreateAsync);
        DeleteCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(OnDeleteAsync);
    }

    public IAsyncRelayCommand CancelCommand { get; }
    public IAsyncRelayCommand CloseCommand { get; }
    public IAsyncRelayCommand ConfirmCommand { get; }
    public IAsyncRelayCommand DeleteCommand { get; }
}

UserControl:
(If I make the bindings here TwoWay, then it works as it should - but the commands should be ReadOnly really)
<UserControl x:Class="App.Lib.Windows.UserControls.Resources.AddedWordEditorUserControl"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:App.Core.ViewModels.AddedWords;assembly=Core"
             xmlns:ux="clr-namespace:App.UI.Windows.Controls;assembly=UI.Windows"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:EditorViewModel}">

<ContentControl x:Name="ccFooter"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Template="{DynamicResource DialogFooter}"
                ux:DialogFooter.CancelButtonCommand="{Binding CancelCommand}"
                ux:DialogFooter.ConfirmButtonCommand="{Binding ConfirmCommand}"
                ux:DialogFooter.ConfirmButtonLabel="Save"
                ux:DialogFooter.DeleteButtonCommand="{Binding DeleteCommand}"
                ux:DialogFooter.DeleteButtonLabel="Delete Added Word"
                ux:DialogFooter.DeleteButtonIsVisible="{Binding IsEditing, Mode=TwoWay}" />

</UserControl>

DialogFooter.cs:
public static class DialogFooter
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ConfirmButtonCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ConfirmButtonCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(DialogFooter),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnConfirmButtonCommandPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnConfirmButtonCommandPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is not FrameworkElement element)
            return;

        element.CalculateConfirmButtonVisibility();
    }

    public static ICommand GetConfirmButtonCommand(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        return element is null
               ? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(element))
               : (ICommand)element.GetValue(ConfirmButtonCommandProperty);
    }

    public static void SetConfirmButtonCommand(FrameworkElement element, ICommand value)
    {
        if (element is null)
            return;

        element.SetValue(ConfirmButtonCommandProperty, value);
    }
}

ContentControlStyle.xaml:
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
                    xmlns:b="clr-namespace:App.UI.Windows.Behaviors"
                    xmlns:ux="clr-namespace:App.UI.Windows.Controls">
                    
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="DialogFooter" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
  
    <Button x:Name="btnConfirm"
            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                              Path=(ux:DialogFooter.ConfirmButtonCommand)}"
            Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                              Path=(ux:DialogFooter.ConfirmButtonLabel)}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                              Path=(ux:DialogFooter.ConfirmButtonIsEnabled)}"
            Template="{DynamicResource DialogFooter.Button}"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"         
            Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                              Path=(ux:DialogFooter.ConfirmButtonVisibility)}">
                         
    </Button>

  </ControlTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>

Edit...
Code from ListViewModel, this is how the EditViewModel is initialised:
private Task OnEditAsync(SelectedViewModel? selectedItem)
{
    if (selectedItem != null && AllowEdits)
    {
        var editor = new EditorViewModel(_service, _confirmationService, _logger)
        {
            OnDeletion = id => _service.DeleteAsync(id),
            IsEditing = true
        };

        editor.Initialise(new Word(selectedItem.WrittenForm, selectedItem.Language, selectedItem.SpokenForms) { Id = selectedItem.Id });

        editor.RequestClose += () => SelectionChanged?.Invoke(this, null!);

        SelectionChanged?.Invoke(this, editor);
    }
    else
    {
        SelectionChanged?.Invoke(this, null!);
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}


Why do you have these attached properties at all? You could as well write <Button x:Name="btnConfirm" Command="{Binding ConfirmCommand}" ... />. And which DataContext is actually changing? Where does that happen? As a note, animated GIFs are the most annoying thing ever.

If I just do 'Command="{Binding DeleteButtonCommand}"' then nothing happens when I click the button.
Yes, they are quite annoying.
The EditorViewModel is reloaded when you switch from English to German. The rest of the control sees this change (you can see 'Word' textbox updated, but the buttons do not react to this.

What does "EditorViewModel is reloaded" mean exactly? Is a new instance of EditorViewModel assigned to the DataContext of AddedWordEditorUserControl?

I have added the code from ListViewModel (this is on the left of the screen), each time I click an item there on the left it runs this code.

That's still not what I have asked for. It appears as if you are invoking a custom SelectionChanged event. What does that have to do with the change of an AddedWordEditorUserControl's DataContext? And the GIF does not explain anything. Consider removing it, then readers of your question wouldn't have to block it again and again after your edits. Also take at look at How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

The DataContext remains as an instance of EditorViewModel.
but it is the content of EditorViewModel has changed (as can be seen in the right of the screen)
If I change one line: ux:DialogFooter.ConfirmButtonCommand="{Binding ConfirmCommand}" to ux:DialogFooter.ConfirmButtonCommand="{Binding ConfirmCommand, Mode=TwoWay}" then everything works fine, BUT, that means that I have to set my Commands to non-ReadOnly, which doesnt seem right

If I would have to guess, I'd say that you somewhere explictly set the DataContext of the UserControl. That typically breaks everything and must not be done.

Only here:  d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:EditorViewModel }">

Ok, that's only the design-time DataContext, not the actual one at runtime. Besides that, it is still unclear how all those code fragments work together.
